# How to stop all threads if there is an exception in one thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I am currently running a function using python's concurrent.futures library. It looks like this (I am using Python 3.10.1 ):

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:

future_results = [executor.submit(f.get_pdf_multi_thread, ssn) for ssn in ssns]

for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_results):
    try:
        future.result()
    except Exception as exc:
        # If there is one exception in a thread stop all threads
        for future in future_results:
            future.cancel()
        raise exc
```

**The aim of this is that, if there is any exception in one of the threads, stop the remaining ones and throw exception**. However I don't know if this is doing what it's supposed to do (sometimes it takes a lot of time to throw the exception that I desire and some other times it throws it quickly). Could you help me with this? Thank you

Comment: what about `sys.exit`?

Comment: Just use [`executor.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map).

Comment: Maybe you can use `Coroutine` instead of multi threads.

Comment: what about set variablue run to true or false?

Comment: Seriously, `list(executor.map(f.get_pdf_multi_thread, ssns))` will shutdown all threads if exception raised.

Comment: The code that I wrote shouldn’t stop all threads if one of them throws an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Olvin Roght advice I've successfully managed to complete the task

```
list(executor.map(f.get_pdf_multi_thread, ssns))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [executor.shutdown(wait=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) method

Comment: The solution posted by @Olvin Roght did the job

Comment: takin a look inside the map method, it indeed apply future.cancel() on others, but remove the current futures who finished to it dont get cancelled, maybe cancelling a future already done is weird